# What happens to timer in OnPause onResume

Tags: android, timer, cycle

I'm still a bit unfamiliar with life cycles in android. However, in my app I have a timer that's run every ten seconds. I notice that when the screen is rotated, the app goes back to home screen and crashes (probably has something to do with the timer). Any ideas?

Comment: If it crashes, it will produce red-colored logs in the LogCat. Post those if you want us to take a look at the reason for the crash. Remember that orientation change calls all of `onPause, onStop, onDestroy, onCreate, onStart, onResume`.

Comment: What are you doing every 10 seconds?

Answer (score 0):

in onPause you must stop the timer. read your logcat logs for details.

Comment: I thought about this but there would be problem because if I were to rotate it so many times in such a small window of time, it would create too many timers?

Comment: I suggest you cancel your timer at that point and create a new timer onResume. The garbage collector should recycle them for you once you drop the reference to the previous timer.

Comment: I was thinking about this but onResume occurs after onStart. Should I just not create a new timer in onStart(when I first start the app), and make one in onResume (instead). Because If I put one in onResume, onStart will create a timer and then onResume will create one as well (or at least it seems so). We'll always have 2 in the case where we first start the app.